# Desktop background is stuck in slide show

Tags: windows, slideshow

I have a 3-4-year-old dell Inspiron running Windows 10 that is stuck on slideshow on the desktop. I just want to stop it altogether. The standard way to stop this is to right click on the desktop, and click on personalize and choose a picture.

If doing this 500 times would work, my problem would be solved. Once in awhile I've found advice about going into the power settings, and that hasn't worked either.

Does someone have any other ideas?

Thanks, Diane

Answer (score 0):

Some very brief googling lead me to [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-remove-the-slideshow-option-in-windows-10/103f1b77-4b2b-4e4d-b901-e2c36b939ec6#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20Settings%20by%20simply,preferred%20picture%20by%20clicking%20Browse.) microsofts answer post that seems to answer your question.